# What is the key for my NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, ios, json, nsdictionary

I have created an NSDictionary from a JSON file, but when I try to do

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *currentObject = [JSONdata objectForKey:key];
```

I error receive and error of `-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

When I do an `NSLog` of `JSONdata` this is my output:

```
(
    {
        1 =         {
            description = "";
            facets =             (
                                {
                    name = Red;
                },
                                {
                    name = Blue;
                },
                                {
                    name = Skinny;
                },
                                {
                    name = Standard;
                },
                                {
                    name = "Navy Blue";
                }
            );
            id = 1073;
            owner = 1001;
            "post_date" = 1341980987;
            transaction = 24;
            username = TonyB;
        };
    },
    {
        2 =         {
            description = "";
            facets =             (
                                {
                    name = "Bow Tie";
                },
                                {
                    name = Blue;
                },
                                {
                    name = Orange;
                },
                                {
                    name = Yellow;
                }
            );
            id = 1001;
            owner = 1001;
            "post_date" = 1340640012;
            transaction = 6;
            username = TonyB;
        };
    }
)
```

Am I correcting in thinking that the first set of keys that I should be able to get should be `1` and `2` using `[JSONdata objectForKey:@"0"]` or `[JSONdata objectForKey:@"1"]`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: But that's a very curious JSON layout. Are you stuck with that layout or are you open to some more logical structures? I personally would lean towards a simple array of dictionaries, rather than an array of dictionaries, of which each dictionary has one key (that's different for each), whose value is yet another dictionary (which you presumably wanted to be your final `currentObject`). You can write code to extract what you want, but you'll be contorting yourself to do something that really lends itself to a far simpler, more elegant structure.

Comment: I agree with Rob this is the strangest JSON I've seen.

Comment: @Rob I am more than willing to reformat my JSON. I am creating it via PHP's `json_encode`.  Given a bit of help getting it to come out cleaner would be great.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13757046/1271826) below, in which I show you PHP code that generates simplified JSON, and then I show you how simple the resulting Objective-C is when the JSON is cleaned up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure of your JSON is as Follow

NSArray containing NSDictionary

So you need to do this : `[[JSONdata objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"1"]`

---

Also when in doubt you can always do this :
`NSLog(@"JSONdata class == %@", [JSONdata class]);`

And when you hit a [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you always have this method : `- (NSArray *)allKeys` that will return you an array of all the key of that dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

You have `NSArray` then `NSDictionary`. Also You are sending `key` as `NSString` where as it is a `int` in json. Could that be it ?

does this help `[[JSONdata objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"1"];`

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would throw a compiler error in any case unless the key was in a wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
NSArray *currentObject = [JSONdata valueForKey:key];
```

Your JSONdata is an Array and not Dictionary. So that doesnt have any `objectForKey` method. The above one will invoke [`valueForKey` on its objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/valueForKey%3a) and will return the result as an Array. If you just want to access the first object, you can directly use `[[JSONdata objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:key];` too. If the above one is used, just use

```
NSDictionary *currentDict = [currentObject objectAtIndex:0];
```

Ideally a simple solution would look like this,

```
NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",indexPath.row];
NSDictionary *currentObject = [[JSONdata objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row - 1)] valueForKey:key];
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a very curious JSON layout. This is an array of dictionaries, of which each dictionary has one key (that's different for each), whose object is a dictionary. I'd suggest a simple array of dictionaries.

Thus, you might have the following PHP. I assume you're reading from a database or something, but it will give you a sense of what JSON structure I'm suggesting, where this is simply an array of dictionaries. I also simplified `facets`, too, but whether you go that far is up to you. But the key issue is that the PHP is just generating a simple array of dictionaries:

```
<?php

    $object1 = array(
                   "description" => "", 
                   "facets" => array (
                       "Red",
                       "Blue",
                       "Skinny",
                       "Standard",
                       "Navy Blue"
                    ),
                    "id" => 1073,
                    "owner" => 1001,
                    "post_date" => 1341980987,
                    "transaction" => 24,
                    "username" => "TonyB");

    $object2 = array(
                   "description" => "", 
                   "facets" => array (
                       "Bow tie",
                       "Blue",
                       "Orange",
                       "Yellow"
                    ),
                    "id" => 1071,
                    "owner" => 1001,
                    "post_date" => 1340640012,
                    "transaction" => 6,
                    "username" => "TonyB");

    $results = array($object1, $object2);

    echo json_encode($results);

?>
```

That will generate the following JSON (which I've prettified):

```
[
    {
        "description" : "",
        "facets" : [
             "Red",
             "Blue",
             "Skinny",
             "Standard",
             "Navy Blue"
        ],
        "id" : 1073,
        "owner" : 1001,
        "post_date" : 1341980987,
        "transaction" : 24,
        "username" : "TonyB"
    },
    {
        "description" : "",
        "facets" : [
             "Bow tie",
             "Blue",
             "Orange",
             "Yellow"
        ],
        "id" : 1071,
        "owner" : 1001,
        "post_date" : 1340640012,
        "transaction" : 6,
        "username" : "TonyB"
    }
]
```

You can then read this JSON the standard way:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSError *error;
NSArray *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
```

Finally, your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` or `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` can now just simply do:

```
NSDictionary *currentObject = jsonData[indexPath.row];
```

Or, if you're using a version of Xcode earlier than version 4.5, you would:

```
NSDictionary *currentObject = [jsonData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: If you have a question on the PHP to generate this JSON, submit another PHP tagged question with your PHP source and add a comment here with a link to that question, so I can find it easily.